# antd Button className style is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, antd

Facing issues using antd Button; need to align a button in right. Yes it works with `style={{float:"right"}}` but need to style it in className properties.

```
 <Button className={styles.myButtonOne} type="default" htmlType="button"> My Button</Button>
```

```
.myButtonOne {
    float: right;
}
```

this is not working though used float left in `myButtonOne`.
But following code working fine:

```
 <Button style={{float:'right'}} type="default" htmlType="button"> My Button</Button>
```

Need to use styles in className.

Comment: the `class` attribute is used to add a class to an HTML element. For example `<button class="example-class">submit</button>`. If your library violates that syntax then I would recommend you stop using that library.

Comment: Just give the class `className="myButtonOne"` If you are using `css`.

Comment: @Ankit, I appreciate your suggestions. it doesn't working sorry. Fix the issue in another way; wrapping the button inside Col and Row.```<Col><Row justify="end"><Button type="default" htmlType="button"}>My Button</Button></Row></Col>.

Comment: the [ant.design's button doc](https://ant.design/components/button#api) shows no sign of `className` property meaning Button component doesn't accept `className` property.

Comment: @Pabel Mahbub if you have defined the CSS then className will definitely work.

Comment: @Ankit using scss in the app.

Answer (score 0):

According to one comment by @Layhout, there is no className property on Button so you can wrap the button in a div and give that div the `className={styles.myButtonOne}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'antd'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledButton = styled.div`
  & .my-btn {
    float: right;
  }
`

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <StyledButton>
      <Button className="my-btn" type="default" htmlType="button">
        My Button
      </Button>
    </StyledButton>
  )
}

export default Page
```